# NodeJS: Insert record in dynamodb if not exist

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I need to store user's info in DynamoDB and send a mail to the same user if it doesn't already exist in DynamoDB table.  I am doing this in for loop. The list contains only 2 records. The issue is only the second record gets inserted in table and the mail is sent twice to the same user. Here is the code:

```
module.exports.AddUser = function(req, res, usersList, departmentId) {
    var _emailId = "";
    var _userName = "";
    var _departmentId = departmentId;

    for (var i = 0; i < usersList.length; i++) {
        _emailId = usersList[i].emailId;
        _userName = usersList[i].userName;
        var params = {
            TableName: "UsersTable",
            Key: {
                "emailId": _emailId,
                "departmentId": _departmentId
            }
        };

        docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
            if (!err) {
                if (!data.items)
                    AddUserAndSendEmail("UsersTable", _emailId, _userName);
                    //The above function is being called twice but for the same user. 
                    //It has a check so not inserting the same record twice but
                    //sending two mails to the same user.
            }
        });
    }
    res.end("success");
}

function AddUserAndSendEmail(tableName, emailId, _userName) {
    var params = {
        TableName: tableName,
        Item: {
            "emailId": emailId,
            "departmentId": 101//Default Department
        }
    };

    docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
        if (!err) {
            //Send Email Code Here
        } else {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
}
```

What could be the reason for this strange behavior? Really frustrated, I am about to give up on this.

Comment: what is the email ID of the other entry?  so far the code should be correct.

Comment: @HeadhunterXamd They both are different. Verified.

Comment: maybe check/show the code behind the `AddUserAndSendEmail`? The problem could be in that function.

Comment: @HeadhunterXamd I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

1) Please note that DynamoDB is **eventually consistent**. If you insert the item and check whether the item exists immediately, it may not always find the item in the database.

This means the second iteration of the loop **may not always** find the first item inserted into the table.

2) If the item already exists in the table, the `Put` api will update the item and give successful response.

This means the Put will be successful for the same `email id` and `department id` in the second iteration because it updates the record if it is already present.

> GetItem – The GetItem operation returns a set of Attributes for an
>   item that matches the primary key. The GetItem operation provides an
>   eventually consistent read by default. If eventually consistent reads
>   are not acceptable for your application, use ConsistentRead.
>
> PutItem – Creates a new item, or replaces an old item with a new item
>   (including all the attributes). If an item already exists in the
>   specified table with the same primary key, the new item completely
>   replaces the existing item. You can also use conditional operators to
>   replace an item only if its attribute values match certain conditions,
>   or to insert a new item only if that item doesn’t already exist.

Based on the above points, there is a possibility to get two emails if you have same `email id` and `department id` in the array.